# how to add spark package to eclipse

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to create spark project with java in eclipse

I studied a lot of pages and movies on google but I dont understand exactly what I must do ?

finally downloaded this eclipse:

> Scala IDE 4.6.1

but this version dont have spark packages.
now how install spark packages on it.

I read this pdf but dont help me.

```
http://freecontent.manning.com/wp-content/uploads/how-to-start-developing-spark-applications-in-eclipse.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Maven project in eclipse and add spark as dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As long as you are running it in standalone mode you should be able to test your code.

Please visit [create-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39279/create-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/) to learn more about Maven Projects.

Cheers !

Comment: I opened the new maven project window. now how to declare a dependency here ?

Comment: Copy the dependency from the answer in pom.xml file.

Comment: in window of 'new maven project' step2 ask me to choose an ArcheType. what arche I must choose? see this: https://ibb.co/bPzPM5

Comment: You can create a simple project, added a link in answer which shows it.